# Calculate finishing positions 1st, 2nd=, 2nd=, etc

Tags: javascript

I am trying to efficiently produce a finishing position for a given set a results where I want to account for a duplicate point scores and then increment the finishing position following a large group of joint scores. For example three 5th place finishes leaves the next position finisher in 8th:

[image: table]

I am trying to accurately assign the correct finishing position for an ordered set of points but my code fails to increment correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/ph7kz56x/1/

```
const position = (place, equals) => {
  const joint = equals ? '=' : '';
  if (place.toString().endsWith(1) && !place.toString().endsWith(11)) return `${place}st${joint}`;
  if (place.toString().endsWith(2)) return `${place}nd${joint}`;
  if (place.toString().endsWith(3)) return `${place}rd${joint}`;
  return `${place}th${joint}`
}

const standings = [{
    "name": "Team A",
    "points": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Team B",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team C",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team D",
    "points": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "Team E",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team F",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team G",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team H",
    "points": 4
  }
];

standings.reduce((positions, result, index) => {
  const jointPoints = standings.filter(r => r.points === result.points);
  if (jointPoints.length > 1) {
    // somewhere here I should check if the .position has been set, rather than override it
    // hence the bug in the output.
    return [...positions, ...jointPoints.map(r => {
      r.position = position(index + 1, true);
      return r;
    })]
  } else {
    result.position = position(index + 1, false);
    return [...positions, result];
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One liner fix for your code

+2 because :

1) index starts at zero and your count starts at 1

2) length starts from 1 so you need to add +1 to index

```js
const position = (place, equals) => {
  const joint = equals ? '=' : '';
  if (place.toString().endsWith(1) && !place.toString().endsWith(11)) return `${place}st${joint}`;
  if (place.toString().endsWith(2)) return `${place}nd${joint}`;
  if (place.toString().endsWith(3)) return `${place}rd${joint}`;

  return `${place}th${joint}`
}

const standings = [{
    "name": "Team A",
    "points": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Team B",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team C",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team D",
    "points": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "Team E",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team F",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team G",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team H",
    "points": 4
  }
];

standings.reduce((positions, result, index) => {
  const jointPoints = standings.filter(r => r.points === result.points);
  if (jointPoints.length > 1) {
    return [...positions, ...jointPoints.map(r => {
    //This is all you need
      r.position = position(index -jointPoints.length+2, true);
      return r;
    })]
  } else {
   result.position = position(index + 1, false);
    return [...positions, result];
  }
}, []);

console.log(standings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check wether `result` is already included in `position` and if so, skip. But honestly this could also just be done with a very simple for loop:

```js
standings = [{
    "name": "Team A",
    "points": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Team B",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team C",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team D",
    "points": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "Team E",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team F",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team G",
    "points": 7
  }, {
    "name": "Team H",
    "points": 4
  }
];

let position = 0;
for(const [index, standing] of standings.entries()) {
  const eqPrev = index > 0 && standings[index - 1].points === standing.points;
  const eqNext = index < standings.length - 1 && standings[index + 1].points === standing.points;
        
  if(!eqPrev) position = index + 1;

  standing.position = ((eqPrev || eqNext) ? "=" : "") + position;
}

console.log('standings:', JSON.stringify(standings, null, 2))
```

Comment: just added code snippet so we can run automagically, fell free to revert if you think it's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `standings` are pre-sorted (if not, sort them in the caller using `standings.sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points)`, simply compare the current index to the previous index and apply the ranking logic you need. Specifically, keep a running accumulator like `currentRank` and only increment it when the current and previous elements don't match.

```js
const toOrdinal = n => {
  const ord = ["", "st", "nd", "rd"][("" + n).slice(-1)];
  return !ord || n > 10 && n < 20 ? n + "th" : n + ord;
};

const rank = standings => {
  let currentRank = 1;
  
  return standings.map((e, i) => {
    const prev = standings[i-1];
    
    if (!i || e.points < prev.points) {
      currentRank = i + 1;
    }

    e.rank = toOrdinal(currentRank);
    
    if (i && e.points === prev.points) {
      prev.rank = prev.rank.replace(/=*$/, "=");
      e.rank += "=";
    }
    
    return e;
  });
};

const standings = [{
    "name": "Team A",
    "points": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "Team B",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team C",
    "points": 9
  },
  {
    "name": "Team D",
    "points": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "Team E",
    "points": 7
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Team F",
    "points": 7
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Team G",
    "points": 7
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Team H",
    "points": 4
  }
];

console.log(rank(standings));
```

Also, there is a bug in your `position` function: `position(12, false) => 12nd`. Any teen number should be `th`, not just 11. A minor design point, but this function could be less overloaded if it didn't worry about the `=` formatting as a flag, which isn't a property of a number, but rather the relationship between numbers. This boolean has little semantic meaning for the calling code.